# Running TriggerIO iOS app with screen locked?

Tags: ios, html, avaudioplayer, background-process, trigger.io

I have a fitness app that guides users through a workout, but in order to do that, the app must remain active even while in the background. Specifically, this is crucial with our new audio release, which guides the user through their workout using audio cues that cut in and out. Currently, I'm using [TriggerIO's implementation to play audio](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html#createaudioplayer) which also [allows background audio](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html#config), but only continues background execution until the audio file finishes. Additionally, I will soon replace that with a [native plugin](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/index.html) that includes background-music ducking.

Is there a way for me to continue running my HTML5 app in the background after an audio file finishes playing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to keep the webview running permanently in the background on iOS - there are a limited set of tasks which are allowed to run in the background: see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Depending on how predictable your audio playback requirements are, you might be able to get by with using Local Notifications (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194), which would be simpler because your app wouldn't need to request extra UIBackgroundModes.

If local notifications aren't going to work for you, get in touch at support@trigger.io: we don't yet have a way for plugins to request new background processing modes, but it's definitely something we can add.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, James! Local Notifications won't work for me but requesting a background processing mode will. I'll contact support.